# Convert image to string (for Symfony2 Response)

Tags: php, image, symfony

I'm building a script for image resizing in Symfony2.

As I'd like to be able to use standard Symfony2 response system...

```
$headers = array('Content-Type'     => 'image/png',
                 'Content-Disposition' => 'inline; filename="image.png"');

return new Response($img, 200, $headers);  // $img comes from imagecreatetruecolor()
```

...I need a string to send as a response. Unfortunately, functions like `imagepng` do only write files or output directly to the browser, not return strings.

So far the only solutions I was able to think of are

1] save the image to a temporary location and then read it again

```
imagepng($img, $path);
return new Response(file_get_contents($path), 200, $headers);
```

2] use output buffering

```
ob_start();
imagepng($img);
$str = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

return new Response($str, 200, $headers);
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: I recommend using [ImagineBundle](https://github.com/avalanche123/AvalancheImagineBundle). In my opinion it's a really nice bundle for any sort of image manipulation. Although it comes with only a single filter (thumbnail creation), you may write your own bundles. Just thought I'd share my find with you :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Output buffering is probably the best solution.

BTW you can call one less function:

```
ob_start();
imagepng($img);
$str = ob_get_clean();
```