# Symfony - how to execute another php script and get results?

Tags: php, post, symfony, execute

I have got script which generates some graphic and returns it as a result, also it caches this graphics etc.

I use symfony2 and in a controller I need to invoke this script, for now I use this function, to invoke my php script:

```
        private function http_post($url, $data)
            {
                $data_url = http_build_query ($data);
                $data_len = strlen ($data_url);

                return array ('content'=>file_get_contents ($url, false, stream_context_create (array ('http'=>array ('method'=>'POST'
                        , 'header'=>"Connection: close\r\nContent-Length: $data_len\r\nContent-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n"
                        , 'content'=>$data_url
                        ))))
                    , 'headers'=>$http_response_header
                    );
            }
```

I think this way isn't the best and as I remember well file_get_contents is pretty slow?
So my question: is it good way to send POST to this script via "http_post"? If not, than what would be better?

EDIT: I don't want to have this script in a controller, so no include solutions please :).

Comment: Is the script that generates the graphic part of your symfony application or is it an individual script floating around somewhere?

Comment: individual script on the same server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wish to implement the image generator as a controller, you would just return the response as normal: `return new Response($generated_image);`.

So this could be your controller:

```
namespace Acme\MyBundle\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class ImageGeneratorController
{
    public function generateAction($parameters)
    {
      //Generate an image using parameters and store it in $image
      $image = ....

      return new Response($image);
    }
}
```

Then, you can [call your image generator from any controller](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/book/controller.html#forwarding) using `forward()`

```
public function indexActionInAnotherController($name)
{
    $response = $this->forward('AcmeMyBundle:ImageGenerator:generate', array(
        'name'  => $name,
        'color' => 'green'
    ));

    // further modify the response or return it directly

    return $response;
}
```

Comment: Yes, after my considerations and your code, I think that it would be the best solution. I had a problem with replace imagepng() to Response object, but I've found this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7365622/convert-image-to-string-for-symfony2-response

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with what you're doing, however if you want to explore an alternative, a lot of people use the curl library, which is fast and robust.

Comment: +1. If this script is not part of your application, that's the best you can do besides using an `include()`, which can get messy.

Comment: actually I've already tested it with curl and to my surprised it works about 2 times slower in my case, but I'm not sure if debug mode or my server on localhost can cause it. I use curl in another script and it works much faster than file_get_contents

Comment: yeah, i've not seen that happen with curl. Since it's compiled it's usual very fast.