# How do I get symfony2 to export to Excel

Tags: excel, symfony

I'm trying to get my symfony2 application to export to Excel. I can get it to write to disk with no problem, but when I try to export it via a symfony response, I get a lot of gobbledygook. Can anyone make a suggestion:

```
function exportAction()
{
    $fname = "/tmp/test_xls.xlsx";
    $php_excel = new \PHPExcel();//
    $php_excel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
    $sheet = $php_excel->getActiveSheet();
    $sheet->setCellValue('A1', 'Hello');
    $sheet->setCellValue('B2', 'world!');

    $writer = new \PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($php_excel);
    $writer->save($fname);

    $content = file_get_contents($fname);
    return new Response(
        $content,
        200,
        array(
            'Content-Type' => 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet; charset=utf-8',
            'Content-Disposition' => 'attachment; filename="test_957export.xlsx"',
            'Content-Transfer-Encoding' => 'application/octet-stream',
            'Content-Length' => strlen($content)
        )
    );
}
```

Comment: Have you tried the `LoveBundle`? I believe it provides a `give_love` setting.

Answer (score 0):

You have invalid header names. Remove the ':' from Content-Transfer-Encoding and Content-Length. If it doesn't help, try removing some of the headers.

Similar question: [Convert image to string (for Symfony2 Response)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7365622/convert-image-to-string-for-symfony2-response) (might be helpful).

Comment: Thanks - that was a typo when transferring the code over. I have tried removing, adding, changing headers. All to no avail.